# How to compare 2 different dataframe columns and add to 1 if equal in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, series

I have 2 dataframes `Table1` & `Table2`

`Table1` example output:

| CustomerID |
| --- |
| CUST_3849502 |
| CUST_3935123 |

`Table2` example output:

| CustomerID | AccountID | TimeCreated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CUST_3849502 | 3823479@store | 2022-04-07T21:38:13.195641Z |
| CUST_3935123 | 343950347@store | 2022-04-07T21:38:13.647964Z |
| CUST_4566768 | 876876465@store | 2022-02-08T15:55:13.857347Z |

I'm trying to add `Table2["AccountID"]` & `Table2["TimeCreated"]` to `Table1` if `Table1["CustomerID"]` is in `Table2["CustomerID"]`

So desired output of `Table1` is:

| CustomerID | AccountID | TimeCreated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CUST_3849502 | 3823479@store | 2022-04-07T21:38:13.195641Z |
| CUST_3935123 | 343950347@store | 2022-04-07T21:38:13.647964Z |

I've tried:

```
for x in Table1["CustomerID"]:
   if Table2["CustomerID"] in x:
     Table1["AccountID"] = Table2["AccountID"]
     Table1["TimeCreated"] = Table2["TimeCreated"]
```

But keep getting `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series` for the 2nd line

Both columns are type `pandas.core.series.Series` so not sure what the issue is here, please help

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the code below accomplishes your intended goal.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['CustomerID']=['CUST_3849502','CUST_3935123']

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df2['CustomerID']=['CUST_3849502','CUST_3935123','trash']
df2['AccountID']=['3823479@store','343950347@store','yeet']
df2['TimeCreated']=['2022-04-07T21:38:13.195641Z','2022-04-07T21:38:13.647964Z','yams']

df3 = pd.merge(df,df2,'left')
print(df3)
```

I noticed you were trying to parse the dataframe column data as a list. This can be accomplished using

```
df["Your Column Name"].to_list()
```

If you didn't want to use "pd.merge", you can 'build out' your lists and add them onto your dataframe (SO LONG AS THE LENGTH OF THE LIST EQUALS THE AMOUNT OF ROWS IN THE DATAFRAME... Otherwise it will throw an IndexError).